# Combine Two Database Columns to Order Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have Rails model `User`, where I have multiple attributes like `id`, `first_name`, `last_name` etc etc, Now the problem I want to solve is that I want to get users and order them by combining (`first_name + last_name`) combined. I thought about it for a while but seriously, I don't even have a remote clue about it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MySQL:

```
User.order('CONCAT(`first_name`, `last_name`)')
```

Comment: perfect answer for combination 2 col

Answer (score 1):

Logic-wise there's no need to join/concat the data in order to sort it. As a matter of precedence the primary sort field will set the context and scope the second sort within the primary sort's context. Just select the first sort column, and the next sort column as a subsort, and so on. For example:

```
          (Sort col 1)  (Sort col 2)
Rec ID 22 Adam          Adam
Rec ID 10 Apple         Aaron
Rec ID 01 Apple         Volar
Rec ID 78 Cal           Adam
Rec ID 42 Cal           Volar 
Rec ID 19 Cookie        Zeta
```

Therefore, something like this will work

```
User model {
  scope :order_by_full_name, -> { order("first_name ASC", "last_name ASC") }  
{

Controller {
  @sorted = User.order_by_full_name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails:

```
User.order(["first_name desc", "last_name desc"])
```

'.order' takes either string or array as parameters. You can then combine multiple columns and directions.